# C# HttpWebRequest not getting the correct page

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm using the following code to get a webpage:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
                request.Method = "GET";
                response = request.GetResponse();
                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

It usually works, but I have a page I must parse that is giving me grief. I cannot link the page directly (it's not accessible to external users unfortunately) but the problem is this: I checked the source code from a browser and the page has the following tag in the head:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="blah blah blah title blah bla" href="http://url_of_the_site/feed/" />
```

Basically the page I'm getting back from my HttpRequest is actually the one indicated in that href, which is a link to the site's RSS feed, instead of getting the actual page I requested. It's like the site is "sensing" something peculiar about my request and thinking I'm a RSS client instead of a browser, or something to that effect.

Any ideas why this is happening? How do I fix this??

Comment: Its impossible to know for sure without seeing the result.  Can you reproduce the issue with `curl`?  What does the request look like in `Fiddler`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the request from a client that works (browser) and one that doesn't work (your code). Observe the differences with Fiddler. Remove them one by one until it starts to work.

Comment: Thanks, great tool, I usually don't do much web stuff so I hadn't heard of it. Turns out I was trying to make GET requests while the brower is using POST.

Answer (score -1):

Use [xNet](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet) for HttpRequests, e.g.

```
using(var request=new HttpRequest()){
    var response =request.Get("Your link");
    response=request.Post("link","data");
}
```